# Placing sequences of continuous integers into groups

Tags: ruby, algorithm, grouping

I have an array of `Line` objects. Each line has a `row_number` attribute which is an integer:

```
Line.row_number = 1,
Line.row_number = 2,
Line.row_number = 3,
Line.row_number = 5,
Line.row_number = 6,
Line.row_number = 20,
Line.row_number = 24,
Line.row_number = 25,
Line.row_number = 0
```

I would like to create a hash whose keys are integers and values are all the lines that have consecutive `row_numbers`. I would like the hash to look like this:

```
0 => 
Line.row_number = 0,
Line.row_number = 1,
Line.row_number = 2,
Line.row_number = 3,
Line.row_number = 5,
Line.row_number = 6,

1 => 
Line.row_number = 20

2 =>
Line.row_number = 24,
Line.row_number = 25,
```

Could someone give me an idea as to which algorithm I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: Not clear. What is the logic that puts 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 together?

Comment: What do you mean by "values are all the lines ..."? Do you mean that "each value is an **array of** all the lines ..."?

Comment: When you want to represent an array, don't forget to surround it with `[]`. When you want to represent a hash, don't forget to surround it with `{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the array and then iterate over it. If the current element is not equal to the previous one `+1` then a new group is started.

Comment: `sorted_arr = arr.sort_by { |line| line.row_number }`

Comment: Is this not effectively a restatement of the queston?

Answer (score 1):

The example you give in the question is not valid Ruby code, so it is difficult to understand what you want to do.  I have assumed that the essence of your objective is to convert an array:

```
[1,2,24,3,5,6,20,25,0]
```

to a hash that looks like this:

```
{ 0=>[0,1,2,3], 1=>[5,6], 2=>[20], 3=>[24,25] }
```

**Code**

```
def hashify(arr)    
  a = arr.sort
  curr_val = a.first
  a.slice_before do |i|
    last_val = curr_val
    curr_val = i
    last_val + 1 < curr_val  
  end.with_index.with_object({}) { |(arr,j),h| h[j]=arr }
end
```

**Example**

```
hashify [1,2,24,3,5,6,20,25,0]
  #=> {0=>[0, 1, 2, 3], 1=>[5, 6], 2=>[20], 3=>[24, 25]}
```

**Explanation**

```
arr = [1,2,24,3,5,6,20,25,0]
a = arr.sort
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 20, 24, 25]
curr_val = a.first
  #=> 0
enum0 = a.slice_before do |i|
      last_val = curr_val
      curr_val = i
      last_val + 1 < curr_val  
    end
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x0000010109aea0>:each>
enum0.to_a
  #=> [[0, 1, 2, 3], [5, 6], [20], [24, 25]]
enum1 = enum0.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: \
  #   #<Enumerator::Generator:0x0000010109aea0>:each>:with_index>
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[[0, 1, 2, 3], 0], [[5, 6], 1], [[20], 2], [[24, 25], 3]]
enum2 = enum1.with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: \
  #   #<Enumerator::Generator:0x0000010109aea0>:each>:with_index>:with_object({})>
enum2.to_a
  #=> [[[[0, 1, 2, 3], 0], {}], [[[5, 6], 1], {}], [[[20], 2], {}], [[[24, 25], 3], {}]]
enum2.each { |(a,j),h| h[j]=a }
  #=> {0=>[0, 1, 2, 3], 1=>[5, 6], 2=>[20], 3=>[24, 25]}
```

`enum0`, `enum1`, `enum2` are all enumerators.  You can think of the latter two as "compound" enumerators.  `enum0.to_a` shows the values `enum0` would pass into its block (if it had one). Same for `enum1.to_a` and `enum2.to_a` (and the latter does have a block).

Consider the last step. The first value of `enum2` that is passed into the block by `each` is `[[0,1,2,3],0],{}]`.  These are assigned to the block variables as follows:

```
a => [0, 1, 2, 3]
j => 0
h => {}
```

and

```
h[0] = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

is executed, so the hash is now:

```
h #=> {0=>[0, 1, 2, 3]}
```

The second value passed into the block by `each` assigns the following values to the block variables:

```
a = [5, 6]
j = 1
h = {0=>[0, 1, 2, 3]}
```

and

```
h[1] = [5, 6]
```

is executed, resulting in:

```
h #=> {0=>[0, 1, 2, 3], 1=>[5, 6]}
```

`each` passes the remaining two values into the block and simliar calculations are performed, after which `h` is returned by the enumerator.

Answer (score -1):

Using `array.sort_by(&:row_number).group_by{ |e| e.row_number.div(10) }`:

```
> Line = Struct.new(:row_number)
> t = 0.upto(20).each.map{ |i| Line.new(i) }.shuffle
> t.sort_by(&:row_number).group_by{ |e| e.row_number.div(10) }
=> {0=>[#<struct Line row_number=0>, #<struct Line row_number=1>, #<struct Line row_number=2>, #<struct Line row_number=3>, #<struct Line row_number=4>, #<struct Line row_number=5>, #<struct Line row_number=6>, #<struct Line row_number=7>, #<struct Line row_number=8>, #<struct Line row_number=9>],
    1=>[#<struct Line row_number=10>, #<struct Line row_number=11>, #<struct Line row_number=12>, #<struct Line row_number=13>, #<struct Line row_number=14>, #<struct Line row_number=15>, #<struct Line row_number=16>, #<struct Line row_number=17>, #<struct Line row_number=18>, #<struct Line row_number=19>],
    2=>[#<struct Line row_number=20>]}
```